# How is might calculated in Kingdoms of Camelot?

Tags: kingdoms-of-camelot

I have been playing kingdoms of Camelot for a few days now an I still cannot determine how might is calculated.

I'm aware might goes down when you send troops out of your base, but I had a significant amount of might left over when I only had transport troops left in my base during a march - which made me wonder:

Is might calculated on how many and/or which idle troops you currently own? If so, which troops give higher might ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The might is the sum of the troop-might you currently have.

- Supply troops - 1 might
- T1 troops - 4 might
- T1 wall - 18 might
- T2 troops - 16 might
- T2 wall - 24 might
- T3 troops - 24 might
- T3 wall - 30 might
- T4 troops - 28 might

Sometimes your calculation will be thrown off while reassigning troops or attacking. When your troops return it should balance out properly.

You can use this to know the following facts

- If a player has an odd might, they must have supply troops
- If a player has an even might, but not divisible by 4, they must have either supply troops, t1 wall, or both.

This can be useful when farming.